# Procedure in package without error is not updating table in database

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have got a package with four procedures which works fine. I added another (fifth) procedure to existing package. When I execute new package with five procedures I receive information: "Package body created". When I check table in database which should be updated there is no change and when I check application there is no change as well.

To test/execute package in Toad I press 'Execute a script'. I have checked separately only select statement and only update statement and it works fine (in the way I would expect). It looks like update statement is not working but it might be something else.

I was trying to sort it out for very long time but I do not see where the problem is.

Please find below procedure I would like to add:

```
PROCEDURE procedure_name_test (errbuf OUT VARCHAR2, retcode OUT NUMBER)
IS
    CURSOR c_headers
    IS
        SELECT I.INVOICE_ID, SUM(D.AMOUNT) AS HOLD_VALUE
        FROM APD D,
             API I,
             APH H
        WHERE D.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE = 'ITEM'
        AND D.BASE_AMOUNT IS NULL
        AND D.PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID IS NULL
        AND D.UNIT_PRICE IS NULL
        AND I.PAY_GROUP_LOOKUP_CODE = 'RESALE'
        AND H.hold_lookup_code = 'ITEM NOT ON PO'
        AND H.RELEASE_LOOKUP_CODE IS NULL
        AND H.RELEASE_REASON IS NULL
        AND I.INVOICE_ID = D.INVOICE_ID
        AND D.INVOICE_ID = H.INVOICE_ID  
        GROUP BY I.INVOICE_ID
        HAVING SUM(AMOUNT) < 100
        AND ( SUM(AMOUNT) < 50
            OR ( MAX(AMOUNT) < 50 AND MIN(AMOUNT) < 50) );

    v_rec_count NUMBER := 0;
    COUNT1 NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN

    FOR c_headers_r IN c_headers
    LOOP
        v_rec_count := v_rec_count + 1;
        fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.output,
            'No Of Invoices with Immaterial ITEM NOT ON PO Hold : '
                || v_rec_count );
        UPDATE APH
        SET last_update_date = SYSDATE,
            last_updated_by = fnd_profile.VALUE ('USER_ID'),
            release_lookup_code = 'Immaterial Matching Rel',
            release_reason = 'Immaterial matching difference TEST '
                || TRIM (TO_CHAR (c_headers_r.HOLD_VALUE,'L999G999G999G990D99'))
                || ' (system)',   
            last_update_login = (SELECT MAX (submitted_login_id)
                                 FROM applsys.fnd_logins
                                 WHERE user_id = fnd_profile.VALUE ('USER_ID')),
            responsibility_id = fnd_profile.VALUE ('RESP_ID')

        WHERE RELEASE_LOOKUP_CODE IS NULL
        AND HOLD_LOOKUP_CODE = 'ITEM NOT ON PO';

        commit;

        COUNT1 := COUNT1 + 1;

    END LOOP;

    fnd_file.put_line (FND_FILE.output,
        'No Of Invoices where Immaterial Hold released : '|| COUNT1);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        fnd_file.put_line (FND_FILE.output,'No data Found');

    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Immaterial hold is not Released:'
            ||SQLERRM);    
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message "Package body created" means that you have succesfully compiled the new code in the database. Next step is to actually run your code.

Something like this:

```
declare
  l_error_buffer varchar2(32767);
  l_retcode number;
begin
  package_name.procedure_name_test (l_error_buffer, l_retcode);
end;
/
```

Comment: Rene, Thank you very much for your response. I was just wondering how can I get value of error_buffer?

Comment: @user3033092 - your procedure isn't populating either of your `out` parameters, so they're pointless at the moment and there is nothing to display. You seem to be logging to a file, maybe, through `fnd_file`, so any messages are being swallowed by that. It's possible you'd be able to see the `output` at least if you `set serveroutput on`, or whatever Toad's equivalent is, but it depends what `fnd_file` is actually doing.